# Stripe elements getting destroyed

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have this javascript code that creates a modal dinamically with a div where stripe loads it's element divs to store my clients card details. Since they can show and hide modal, I devided to hook a calback into the hidden event of the modal and remove it from the dom. Meaning every time the user clicks the button to add a new payment method, he gets a new modal added to the dom. Also, to prevent duplicate strip elements of the same type on the same page, I destroy the "element". On the first try everything works great, but after each attempt to "destroy" the elements stripe throws an exception saying the element has already been destroyed.

Here's the code:

```
static createNewPaymentMethod() {
    var stripe = Stripe("My_Publishable_Key");

    var modal = "<DIVS_WITH_THE_MODAL>";

    $("body").append(modal);
    $("#ID_OF_THE_MODAL").modal("show");

    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var stripeCardElement = elements.create('card');

    stripeCardElement.mount('#ID_OF_THE_MODAL .card-element');

    $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#ID_OF_THE_MODAL", function(){
        stripeCardElement.destroy();
        $("#ID_OF_THE_MODAL").remove();
    });
}
```

I tried changing the call to the variable ***stripeCardElement*** to ***elements.getElement('card')*** and then calling ***destroy*** on that, but as with the first try, this call returns null after the first modal shows...

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick fix, i changed ***stripeCardElement.destroy();*** to ***stripeCardElement.unmount();*** and it seems to work but i kind of think the way i was coding was actually better.. dont know if there is some diference in the approach inside stripe JS api..

Comment: I'm not clear on the difference between destroy and unmount

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem here in the code.

i.e stripeCardElement.destroy();

for destroying the element you can prefer call back function which will execute after your whole process is done and no longer need of the stripe element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34426002)